# MVC Scaffolding - Missing Classes from Reference Assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Are there any special rules for what is / isn't shown in the MVC scaffolding model class and data context class dropdowns when adding new MVC or WebApi controllers?

We have our data context and models in other assemblies that we reference in the MVC project but only classes and contexts that are in that MVC project are shown.

The referenced assemblies all belong to the same top level namespace e.g. Company.Domain and Company.Data then the MVC project is in Company.UI.

The only way I can see is to copy the classes into the MVC project, then scaffold it, then delete them and re-reference the Company.Data and Company.Domain assemblies.

We are using MVC5 with VS 2013 Update 3

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is two things:

1. Ensure that your MVC project (Company.UI) has a reference to the projects that has the classes you need.
2. The classes are marked as public. By default they would be internal and will not be accessible from another project.

Comment: Classes are all public and the Projects are both referenced.

Comment: So if I add the Company.Data and Company.Domain Projects into the solution then reference them instead using the Add Reference > Solution > Projects they all show up in the dropdowns.

Comment: How are you adding the reference without Add Reference > Solution > Projects?

Comment: Add Reference > Browse > then pick our DLL out of our library folder

Comment: @ASG, Your second comment seems to suggest that you got it working. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes it works that way but we can't do it that way as we won't always have the csproj files, so will be given just the DLL

Comment: @ASG Did you find any solution on how to get this working using only a provided DLL?